# Kronos SQL Query-ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, kronos-workforce-central, oracle12.2

So I'm trying to query Kronos production and I'm coming against the error ORA-00923: "FROM keyword not found where expected ". I've read similar posts and as you can see below, the keyword FROM is the last selected item in the statement.

```
SELECT  A.NAME AS 'Accrual Profile',
        A3.NAME AS 'Accrual Policy',
       "Hidden Accrual Policy" = CASE 
                                      WHEN A2.DISPLAYSW = 1 THEN 'Not Hidden'
                                      ELSE 'Hidden' 
                                 END,
        A4.NAME AS 'Accrual Code',
        A5.NAME AS 'Overflow Accrual Code',
        D.NAME AS 'Length of Service Reference',
        A3.GRANULARITYAMT AS 'Grant',
        A3.FUTOVERDRFTERRAMT AS 'Future overdrafts - disallow amount',
        A3.FUTOVERDRFTWARNAMT AS 'Future overdrafts - warn amount',
        A3.IMPORTOVERRIDE_SW AS 'Override Warnings during Imports',
        A3.GRPEDITOVERRIDE_SW AS 'Override Warnings during Group Edits',
        A3.MAXTAKENAMOUNT,
        A3.MINTAKENAMOUNT,
        A3.USEFTEBALANCEADJSW,
        A3.USESCHEDAMTTYPESW,
        A3.USETODAYSBALNCE_SW,
        P.NAME AS 'Probation',
        P.TYPE AS 'Probation Type',
        T.NAME AS 'Taking Limit',
        D2.NAME AS 'Taking Limit Date Pattern',
        G.NAME AS 'Grant/Limit Name',
        "Limit or Grant Type" = CASE
                                   WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'E' THEN 'Earned Grant'
                                   WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'F' THEN 'Fixed Grant'
                                   WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'B' THEN 'Earning Balance Limit'
                                   WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'A' THEN 'Earning Amount Limit'
                                   WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'C' THEN 'Carry Over Limit'
                                   ELSE 'Other/Cap on Earnings?'
                                END,
         D3.NAME AS 'Grant/Limit Date Pattern'
FROM ACCRUALPROFILE A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALPROFILEMM A2 ON A.ACCRUALPROFILEID = A2.ACCRUALPROFILEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALRULE A3 ON A2.ACCRUALRULEID = A3.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALCODE A4 ON A3.ACCRUALCODEID = A4.ACCRUALCODEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALCODE A5 ON A3.OVRFLWACCRLCODEID = A5.ACCRUALCODEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROBATIONRULE P ON A3.PROBATIONRULEID = P.PROBATIONRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D ON A3.DATESEQUENCEID = D.DATESEQUENCEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRRLTAKELIMITMM A6 ON A3.ACCRUALRULEID = A6.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAKINGLIMIT T ON A6.TAKINGLIMITID = T.TAKINGLIMITID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D2 ON T.DATESEQUENCEID = D2.DATESEQUENCEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRRLGRANTRLMM A7 ON A3.ACCRUALRULEID = A7.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN GRANTRULE G ON A7.GRANTRULEID = G.GRANTRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D3 ON G.DATESEQUENCEID = D3.DATESEQUENCEID
```

Moreover, I tried another solution by changing the enclosed alias in double quotation marks to see if that would work but that produced another set of errors. Lastly, I don't think I'm using any Oracle reserved words as an alias. I was hoping someone could check my code to see where I have got it wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: The column alias for your `CASE` statements should be after the `END`, not `"Limit or Grant Type" = CASE ...`.

Comment: You need to double-quote your aliases, not single quote them.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix involved replacing single quotes with double quotes and then fixing the CaseStatement.

```
SELECT  A.NAME AS "Accrual Profile",
        A3.NAME AS "Accrual Policy",
       CASE 
           WHEN A2.DISPLAYSW = 1 THEN 'Not Hidden'
           ELSE 'Hidden' 
       END,
        A4.NAME AS "Accrual Code",
        A5.NAME AS "Overflow Accrual Code",
        D.NAME AS "Length of Service Reference",
        A3.GRANULARITYAMT AS "Grant",
        A3.FUTOVERDRFTERRAMT AS "Future overdrafts - disallow amount",
        A3.FUTOVERDRFTWARNAMT AS "Future overdrafts - warn amount",
        A3.IMPORTOVERRIDE_SW AS "Override Warnings during Imports",
        A3.GRPEDITOVERRIDE_SW AS "Override Warnings during Group Edits",
        A3.MAXTAKENAMOUNT,
        A3.MINTAKENAMOUNT,
        A3.USEFTEBALANCEADJSW,
        A3.USESCHEDAMTTYPESW,
        A3.USETODAYSBALNCE_SW,
        P.NAME AS "Probation",
        P.TYPE AS "Probation Type",
        T.NAME AS "Taking Limit",
        D2.NAME AS "Taking Limit Date Pattern",
        G.NAME AS "Grant/Limit Name",
       CASE
            WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'E' THEN 'Earned Grant'
            WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'F' THEN 'Fixed Grant'
            WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'B' THEN 'Earning Balance Limit'
            WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'A' THEN 'Earning Amount Limit'
            WHEN G.GRANTTYPE = 'C' THEN 'Carry Over Limit'
            ELSE 'Other/Cap on Earnings?'
        END,
         D3.NAME AS "Grant/Limit Date Pattern"
FROM ACCRUALPROFILE A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALPROFILEMM A2 ON A.ACCRUALPROFILEID = A2.ACCRUALPROFILEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALRULE A3 ON A2.ACCRUALRULEID = A3.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALCODE A4 ON A3.ACCRUALCODEID = A4.ACCRUALCODEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRUALCODE A5 ON A3.OVRFLWACCRLCODEID = A5.ACCRUALCODEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PROBATIONRULE P ON A3.PROBATIONRULEID = P.PROBATIONRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D ON A3.DATESEQUENCEID = D.DATESEQUENCEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRRLTAKELIMITMM A6 ON A3.ACCRUALRULEID = A6.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TAKINGLIMIT T ON A6.TAKINGLIMITID = T.TAKINGLIMITID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D2 ON T.DATESEQUENCEID = D2.DATESEQUENCEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCRRLGRANTRLMM A7 ON A3.ACCRUALRULEID = A7.ACCRUALRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN GRANTRULE G ON A7.GRANTRULEID = G.GRANTRULEID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESEQUENCE D3 ON G.DATESEQUENCEID = D3.DATESEQUENCEID
```